# ruby on rails model association functionality for basic tennis league

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I am fairly new to rails and I am struggling I have looked through a lot of the questions on here and I think my knowledge gap is really holding me up on putting two and two together.

The site is for a womens doubles tennis league.

Here is what I have done so far, I think I need to take a few steps back.

I used rails generate scaffold to create 4 models and controllers with views etc etc.

The models look like this :

```
players:
firstname
lastname
timestamps

teams:
playerone
playertwo
timestamps

fixtures:
team1
team2
court
division
date
timestamps

results:
fixture
set1team1
set1team2
set2team1
set2team2
set3team1
set3team2
team1
team2
timestamps
```

Now I wanted to create associations so that the team has two players (playerone, playertwo), each fixture has two teams (team1, team2).

Then I wanted the fixture in the results model to associate with a record in the fixtures model.

The teams play 3 sets of 6 games so the separate fields in the results model are to record the results of each team in each set of the game and then give a final score to the team. If a team wins the set (first to 6 games) they get an extra 6 points.

Here is what I have attempted with the relationships.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_one :playerone, :class_name => "Player", :foreign_key => "player"
  has_one :playertwo, :class_name => "Player", :foreign_key => "player"
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :fixture
end

class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

I appear to have the knack of views and layouts in rails but I haven't got my head round the powerful side yet.

I have been looking over the many tutorials but this has been really frustrating me and I was hoping someone might help.

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to try and define a relationship for playerone and playertwo.  In your edit view for team,  you would have two selects, each selecting from the list of players.

Same goes with Fixture,  no need for a relationship there either.  In fact, I don't see a need for any relationships right now with the way you've layer out your models,  you just need  to create various selects in your edit views that select from the appropriate models.

Look at it this way,  there are two 'has' relationships,  has_one or has_many,  your approaching it like there is a 'has_two' or 'has_three' relationship,  there are no such relationships,  those facts are already hardcoded in your model attributes.

Comment: So I should remove the relationships for team and players and just use a select so the table column contains the same data but they are not related ? 

And then the same for fixtures ?

Comment: Yes,  your view (the selects for player one and player two are in effect enforcing the proper relationship.